# Dúvida sobre Javascript ou jquery para collapse em viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, collapse, viewport

Criei um botão collapse "pesquisa avançada" para mobile (768px), gostaria que ele iniciasse fechado apenas na resolução 768px para ganhar espaço na tela.

Inicia atualmente assim:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria="" expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" class="btn btn-default btn-mob-block btn-sm btn-icon mb10 hidden-lg">
   <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Pesquisa Avançada
</button>


<div id="collapseExample" style="" aria-expanded="true" class="collapse in">
    <div> Conteúdo da div a ser exibido... </div>
</div>
```

Quando clico, ele fecha e assume essa propriedade, e é assim que eu gostaria que iniciasse na resolução 768px:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria="" expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-default btn-mob-block btn-sm btn-icon mb10 hidden-lg collapsed">
  <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Pesquisa Avançada
</button>

<div id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
    <div> Conteúdo a ser exibido... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc está usando Bootstrap?

Comment: Estou usando Bootstrap sim.

Comment: Cara a pergunta não ficou muito clara, seu collpase já inicia fechado, se ele só aparece abaixo de 768px e já está fecha por padrão quando aparece eu não entendi a sua dúvida

Comment: A principio, nasce tudo aberto, o botão é para expandir o collapse no mobile. Tem que nascer fechado para ganhar espaço na tela.

Comment: hugocsl, re-editei a pergunta para ficar mais clara.

Comment: Ah, então ele aparece em telas menores que 768px e deve estar fechado, mas ele tb aparece em telas maiores que 768px e deve estar aberto é isso? Ou em telas maiores ele tb pode iniciar fechado?

Comment: Em telas menores fechado, em telas maiores aberto. 
Utilizei a classe css hidden-lg para que o botão não apareça em telas maiores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se este código atende seu problema:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#collapseExample").removeClass('in'); 
    if ($(document).width() > 768) {
        $("#collapseExample").addClass('in');
    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.